# How to replace text after the cursor location in VIM

Tags: vim, replace

Suppose I have one line:

```
Linux is not_ Linux
```

My cursor lies on the `_` mark and I want to replace the second `Linux` to `Unix`,how can I do that in vim?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following key sequence:

<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>e</kbd> Unix <kbd>Esc</kbd> *(note the space character before "Unix")*

Here's a brief explanation:

- <kbd>c</kbd>: "<kbd>c</kbd>hange" command, similar to <kbd>d</kbd>elete but ends in "insert" mode.
- <kbd>e</kbd>: from the cursor to the <kbd>e</kbd>nd of the following word.
- " Unix": the replacement text
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Return to command mode (always return to command mode!)

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean?

Comment: @xiaohan2012 Those are fairly basic `vim` commands.  It means "change text to end of word", type "space Unix", and "esc" key to exit Insert mode.  If you are unfamiliar with `vim`, learning it enough to use it fluently does take a non-trivial amount of time.  If you are willing to do that, start with the `vimtutor` command.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not replacement. Any hint on using replacement?

Comment: @xiaohan2012 I answered the question you *posted*, by giving you something that would *replace* the word Linux with the word Unix assuming the cursor position you gave.  I don't think *replace* means what you think it means.  If you are talking about `vim`'s replace commands `r` and `R`, they are not the best choices to use here.  If this is not what you are looking for, then ask the right question to get what you want.

Comment: @xiaohan2012 Just do the `vimtutor` once and you know or have seen all these commands